# Autocomplete other field In Modal

Tags: javascript, html

I need some help in modal bootstrap. I want to make autocomplete name field when I choose id column table.

I have modal script like this :

My input field is like this :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>ID</h3>
      <input type="text" name="id" onclick="return  openmodal(this);"/>
    </div>   
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Name</h3>
      <input type="text" name="name"/>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

My modal script like this :

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <table border="1" cellpadding="10" width="50%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><a class="hello" data-id="1" >1</a></td>
                    <td>Robert</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a class="hello" data-id="2" >2</a></td>
                    <td>Julia</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

And then the javascript :

```
    function openmodal(input) {
 
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
  $(".hello").unbind().click(function(event){

      $(input).val($(this).attr("data-id"));
      $('#myModal').modal('hide');
  });
}
```

How to make name field can get autocomplete from id field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the data-id value to match what you want.

```js
function openmodal(input) {
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
}


$(".hello").unbind().click(function(event) {

  $("#input").val($(this).attr("data-id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Modal -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>ID</h3>
      <input type="text" name="id" onclick="return openmodal(this);" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Name</h3>
      <input type="text" id="input" name="name" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <table border="1" cellpadding="10" width="50%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><a class="hello" data-id="Robert">1</a></td>
              <td>Robert</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><a class="hello" data-id="Julia">2</a></td>
              <td>Julia</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks before, but I want to id field is keep showing with value number and name field with value name.

Comment: OK solved, I just only add more data-id.. Thank you for the help..